# A wide position:fixed element won't stay inside scrollable container

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I have a very large table with a `position:fixed` header that stays at the top of the page when you scroll down the page.

I've been trying to enhance this by putting the table inside of a reasonably-sized width container with `overflow:auto` but the fixed container extends outside the div.

Here is a simplified [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp8p2vp8/)

Comment: There's no table in your fiddle.

Comment: I know. I simplified the fiddle - you can still see the issue even with `<div>`s. The header is inside the container which has fixed dimensions and `overflow:auto` but extends outside the boundaries of that container (even though the main content area fits inside of it).

Comment: Elements with fixed positioning are removed from the flow of the document and positioned with respect to the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with overflow stems from your position fixed property for the header element, furthermore the horizontal scroll on the container (unless intentional) should be fixed by adding the overflow-x: hidden property to your container element.

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.content {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Let me know if this is not the answer you're looking for, we can discuss further.